# How output 10 integers per line in Java?

Tags: java, split, integer

The problem is to display the first 50 prime numbers in 5 lines, each of which contains 10 numbers. I've created a program to output the first 50 prime numbers but I don't know how to split them so they output 10 numbers per line. I am a beginner level programmer and I really need help on this.

```
public class Lab4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int num = 0;

        String primeNumbers = " ";

        for (i = 1; i <= 230; i++) 
        {
            int counter = 0;

            for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) 
            {
                if (i % num == 0) 
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }

            if (counter == 2) 
            {
                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            }
        } 

        System.out.println(primeNumbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format your code. It is very hard to read as is

Comment: You'll get better help if you try something first.

Comment: That said, maybe you should be adding your prime numbers to a collection (such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), rather than to a string.  That way, you can later iterate over the collection strategically for display purposes.

Comment: Can't use arrays :( @JonathanWilson

Comment: Why can't you use arrays?  Does somebody out there want you to feel the pain of their absence?

Comment: LOL for this exercise we can't, according to my prof. @JonathanWilson

Comment: Keeping track of whether a number is prime or not by `counter` is probably not the best way. Why not use a boolean variable?

Comment: @GBlodgett Agreed that the use of `counter` is questionable.  That said, we will need a variable to keep track of how many primes we've found as we find them.  Then, as we find each prime, we can simply print to the screen with `System.out.print`.  On every 10th number (ie. `foundPrimeCount % 10 == 0` we use `System.out.println` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count how many items you already added and once you have 10 you need to put new line. Also I changed `String` to `StringBuilder` because concatenating in a loop is not very good, you can read about it here [StringBuilder vs String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

```
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
int lineCounter = 0;

StringBuilder primeNumbers = new StringBuilder();

for (i = 1; i <= 230; i++) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
        if (i % num == 0) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 2) {
        primeNumbers.append(i).append(" ");
        lineCounter++;
    }

    if (lineCounter == 10) {
        primeNumbers.append(System.lineSeparator());
        lineCounter = 0;
    }
}

System.out.println(primeNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this piece of code below after this line in your code: `primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";`

```
    if (newLineCount == 10) {
      primeNumbers += '\n';
      newLineCount = 0;
    }
    newLineCount++;
```

Also init `newLineCount` before the loop: `int newLineCount = 0;`

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, consider using `StringBuilder` instead of `String`, or even better `ArrayList` to store your numbers, then you can have method to print values from your ArrayList in whatever formatted way you want (with tabs, alignment, new lines...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that suits your needs. I haven't changed anything in your code, just added mine to suit your needs.

```
public class print_prime_numbers_10_per_line {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int num = 0;

        String primeNumbers = "";

        for (i = 1; i <= 230; i++) {
            int counter = 0;

            for (num = i; num >= 1; num--) {
                if (i % num == 0) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }

            if (counter == 2) {
                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            }
        }
        String[] integerStrings = primeNumbers.split(" ");

        int[] integers = new int[integerStrings.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < integers.length; x++) {
            integers[x] = Integer.valueOf(integerStrings[x]);
        }

        for (int g = 0; g < integers.length; g++) {
            if (g % 11 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print(integers[g] + " ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bare in mind that there is no 50 prime numbers below 230.